# ng-hide and ng-show not working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to hide and show depending upon data values. I do not know what's wrong with my code. When I look for the data value by looking at console logs they print " [ ] "

**My Controller**

```
$http.get('/bill/billByPatientId/'+patientData.id)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.bills = data;
});
```

**My Html Code**

ng-hide:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-hide='bills'> 
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <strong>No Bills!</strong> There is no history of bill for this
            patient
        </div>
</div>
```

ng-show :

```
<div>
    <table data-ng-show='bills' class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-1 text-center">Bill No</th>
                <th class="col-lg-1 text-center">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="scrollable">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="bill in bills">
                <td class="text-center">{{bill.billNo}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{bill.billDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Problem is showing ng-show contents. Please help.

Comment: have you tried `data-ng-show='bills.length > 0'` ?

Comment: try `ng-hide="bills.length"` or `ng-show="!bills.length"`. An empty array does not defualt to false, the length property does (when it's 0)

Comment: the data from server is blank. Show the problem might be there. You can check by initializing bills by random data.

Comment: " data-ng-show='bills.length > 0'".  This works Thanks... @Nano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me !

Thanks Nano

```
data-ng-show='bills.length > 0' 

data-ng-hide='bills.length > 0'
```

or

```
data-ng-show='bills[0]' 

data-ng-hide='bills[0]'
```